# Return Boolean From One Function Must Affect Another

Tags: javascript, function

I hope the title of this question is somewhat clear, I couldn't figure out how to exactly spell out my problem. Basically I have 3 functions.

Function A:

```
function validUsername(){
if(username.element.value.length > 0){
    if(checkData(username)){
        showMessage(username, true);
    }else{
        showMessage(username, false, 'Username Already In Use');
    }
}
}
```

Basically this field is using AJAX to verify that a username does not already exist in the database. It uses checkData(username) to get a returned true or false boolean and determine if it needs to show a positive or a negative response.

Function B (checkData(username)):

```
function checkData(obj){
var field = getFieldValue(obj.container);

if(field.length != 1){
    field = null;
}

if(xmlObj != null) {
    xmlObj.open("POST", obj.servletUrl, true);
    xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function() { handleServerResponse(obj.container); };
    xmlObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlObj.send("field=" + field); //Post username to Servlet
}
}
```

This is responsible for creating the AJAX request etc. When the request is ready is uses handleServerResponse to display a message back to the screen.

Function C (handleServerResponse):

```
function handleServerResponse(container){
var response = xmlObj.responseText;
if(xmlObj.readyState == 4) {
    if(xmlObj.status == 200){
        if(response.indexOf('null') != -1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Function C returns a boolean value, but how do I also return that boolean value back to Function B so that Function A can receive the response? I have tried:

```
xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function() { return handleServerResponse(obj.container);

return xmlObj.onreadystatechange; //Function B would return this.
```

But it doesn't work properly. I have also thought about setting a global variable of something like serverResponse = true and then returning that response from Function B, but other objects also use this function so I would need a way to reset it after each use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of a function executed asynchronously is useless. You need to do the work you're doing in `validUsername` *in the callback* or in a function that the callback invokes. As written, you're attempting to use `checkData` as though it is synchronous, but it fundamentally is not, since it makes an asynchronous HTTP request. Shifting the work into the `onreadystatechange` callback solves your problem.

Comment: I cannot shift the work to handleServerResponse() because Function A is meant to determine what sort of action should be taken when Function B returns a true or false response. In some cases it will be to showMessage, but in other situations it might be different.

Comment: @ryandlf - Not only *can* you do what I'm suggesting, it's pretty much the *only way*. Nothing prevents you from performing more complex logic inside the HTTP request's callback. You're not limited to showing messages there. You need to invert your perspective on this. Think in terms of events. You kick off a request and then you handle its result when it's done. What you *don't* do is kick off a request and then return its result to the same function that kicked it off. This is basic sync vs. async thinking.

Comment: I have to grant the accepted answer to you because you helped me understand why the other method wasn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to remove function A and place its logic inside Function C:

```
function handleServerResponse(container){
  var response = xmlObj.responseText;
  if(xmlObj.readyState == 4) {
    if(xmlObj.status == 200){
      if(response.indexOf('null') != -1){
          showMessage(username, true);
      }else{
          showMessage(username, false, 'Username Already In Use');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If it difficult to return values from AJAX calls because you either have to make them asynchronously, which kind of defeats the purpose, or have to handle the logic you want in the return handler as I've shown above.

Comment: This is how I have it set up now, but it doesn't work as well as i'd like it to because I need to be able to use Function A to set alternate responses. This code will not always simply return a showMessage. Function A is meant to determine what response it should have.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX calls are Asynchronous, therefore the function checkData() return immediatly, without waiting the server answer. When the answer arrives, it calls the handleServerResponse() function passing it the response.

I suggest you to move the validUsername() checks in the handleServerResponse() to be sure you get the correct answer.